# verbatim environment inside algorithm2e

Tags: verbatim, algorithms, algorithm2e

I need to output `Prolog` style inside `algorithm2e` and It seems that I cannot use `\verb` inside `algorithm2e`.

How can I use `\verb` or `verbatim` for only one line inside `algorithm2e` in Latex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

Since [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) uses a macro-style interface for its programming structures, using `verbatim` directly is a problem. If its use is really necessary, boxing the content before using it allows you to pass it as an argument to the programming structure commands:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\newsavebox{\mycode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \begin{lrbox}{\mycode}
  \verb!%&$*@#*%!
  \end{lrbox}
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e}
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section and \usebox{\mycode}\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The `verbatim` content is stored in `\mycode` *first* using the `lrbox` environment. Subsequent usage of this box is via `\usebox{\mycode}`.

If it's not really necessary, using `\texttt{..}`, say, would (should) suffice. The decide here would be based on whether you have funny characters included in the part you designate as requiring `verbatim`.